# center an image in a div?? CSS confusion

Tags: html, css

Not sure why the images won't center:

http://jsfiddle.net/xtian/BEXDG/

```
<div class="topic-tracker-info">
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="container-topic">
                            <img src="http://demo.omnigon.com/christian_bovine/snmobile/img/topic-1.jpg" alt="">
                            <p>2011 NFL DRAFT</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="mid">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://demo.omnigon.com/christian_bovine/snmobile/img/topic-2.jpg" alt="">
                        <p>NFL Labor Dispute</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://demo.omnigon.com/christian_bovine/snmobile/img/topic-3.jpg" alt="">
                        <p>NHL TRADE DEADLINE</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="trend-nav">
                <a class="prev" href="#">PREVIOUS</a>
                <a href="#" class="pages"><b>LATEST</b></a>
                <a href="#" class="next">NEXT</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


.container{margin: 0 auto;width:90%;padding:0;overflow: hidden;}
.container-center{margin: 0 auto;width:299px;padding:0;overflow: hidden;}
.container-topic{width:100%; margin:0 auto;}
.topic-tracker {float:left; width:100%; border-top:4px solid #000;background-color: #a80500;}
.topic-tracker.nfl{background-color:#005496;}
.topic-tracker.mlb{background-color:#cc9866;}
.topic-tracker h2{background:transparent url(img/sn-logo.png) no-repeat 0 5px; font-size:12px; color:#fff; font-style: italic;padding: 3px 0 3px 16px; margin-bottom:1px;}
.topic-tracker-info{float:left;width:100%;height:140px;background:transparent url(img/topic-bg.gif) repeat-x 0 0; }
.topic-tracker-info ul{float:left;width:100%;padding:5px 0 0 0;}
.topic-tracker-info ul li{float:left;width:30%;text-align:center;margin: 0 auto;}
.topic-tracker-info ul li a{font-size:12px; font-weight: bold; color:#000;line-height: 1.1;margin:0 auto;}
.topic-tracker-info ul li.mid{margin:0 8px;}
.topic-tracker-info ul li img{float:left;width:93px;margin:0 0 2px 0;clear:right;margin: 0 auto;}
.topic-tracker-info ul li p{clear:both;}

.trend-nav{float:left;margin-top:10px;width:100%;}
.trend-nav a{float:left; color:#4e4e4e; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold;}
.trend-nav a.prev{width:40%;float:left;text-align: left;padding-left:13px;background: transparent url(img/arrow-prev.png) no-repeat 0 1px;}
.trend-nav a.next{width:18%;float:right;text-align: right;padding-right:13px;background: transparent url(img/arrow-next.png) no-repeat right 1px;}
.trend-nav p.pages, #wrapper .trend-nav a.pages{float:left;width:20%;height:16px;margin:0 auto;padding-top:2px;background:transparent url(img/pages_bg.png) no-repeat center center; text-align:center;font-size:10px; color:#000;font-weight: normal;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing float:left from the images:

```
.topic-tracker-info ul li img{width:93px;margin:0 0 2px 0;clear:right;margin: 0 auto;}
```

That centered the images for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/BEXDG/5/

```
// HTML:
<div class="topic-tracker-info">
            <div class="container">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="container-topic">
                                <img src="http://demo.omnigon.com/christian_bovine/snmobile/img/topic-1.jpg" alt="">
                                <p>2011 NFL DRAFT</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="mid">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="http://demo.omnigon.com/christian_bovine/snmobile/img/topic-2.jpg" alt="">
                            <p>NFL Labor Dispute</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="http://demo.omnigon.com/christian_bovine/snmobile/img/topic-3.jpg" alt="">
                            <p>NHL TRADE DEADLINE</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="trend-nav">
                    <a class="prev" href="#">PREVIOUS</a>
                    <a href="#" class="pages"><b>LATEST</b></a>
                    <a href="#" class="next">NEXT</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

// CSS:
.container{margin: 0 auto;width:90%;padding:0;overflow: hidden;}
.container-center{margin: 0 auto;width:299px;padding:0;overflow: hidden;}
.container-topic{width:100%; margin:0 auto;}
.topic-tracker { float:left; width:100%; border-top:4px solid #000;background-color: #a80500}
.topic-tracker.nfl{background-color:#005496;}
.topic-tracker.mlb{background-color:#cc9866;}
.topic-tracker h2{background:transparent url(img/sn-logo.png) no-repeat 0 5px; font-size:12px; color:#fff; font-style: italic;padding: 3px 0 3px 16px; margin-bottom:1px;}
.topic-tracker-info{width:100%;height:140px;background:transparent url(img/topic-bg.gif) repeat-x 0 0; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
.topic-tracker-info ul{float:left;width:100%;padding:5px 0 0 0;}
.topic-tracker-info ul li{float:left;width:30%;text-align:center;margin: 0 auto;}
.topic-tracker-info ul li a{font-size:12px; font-weight: bold; color:#000;line-height: 1.1;margin:0 auto;}
.topic-tracker-info ul li.mid{margin:0 8px;}
.topic-tracker-info ul li img{width:93px;margin:0 0 2px 0;clear:right;;margin: 0 auto;}
.topic-tracker-info ul li p{clear:both;}
.trend-nav{float:left;margin-top:10px;width:100%;}
.trend-nav a{float:left; color:#4e4e4e; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold;}
.trend-nav a.prev{width:40%;float:left;text-align: left;padding-left:13px;background: transparent url(img/arrow-prev.png) no-repeat 0 1px;}
.trend-nav a.next{width:18%;float:right;text-align: right;padding-right:13px;background: transparent url(img/arrow-next.png) no-repeat right 1px;}
.trend-nav p.pages, #wrapper .trend-nav a.pages{float:left;width:20%;height:16px;margin:0 auto;padding-top:2px;background:transparent url(img/pages_bg.png) no-repeat center center; text-align:center;font-size:10px; color:#000;font-weight: normal;}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

because you have

```
.topic-tracker-info ul li img {
  float:left;
}
```

once you remove this attribute, or overwrite it with float:none you should also add text-align:center; to your div.container-topic

Answer (score 0):

This should be all the CSS you need:

```
.topic-tracker-info { font-size:10px; }
.topic-tracker-info ul { overflow:hidden; }
.topic-tracker-info ul li { float:left; margin-right:10px; padding-right:10px; width:125px; }
.topic-tracker-info li a { display:block; text-align:center; }
```

Overview:

- First line just set the font-size small enough for jSfiddle...could be removed
- Second line clears the floats of the li's
- Third line floats the LI's left, adds some margin and padding, and sets a width in px value
- Fourth line sets the links to block elements, which means they will take up all of the LI's width, then I set the text-align to center which centers everything inside the !